# Swift: How to determine application folder?

Tags: swift, macos

I just found how to determine the document folder under macOS.
But I like to find the folder, in which my binary is located.
I want to load a file, which is stored in the same directory like my binary.

Comment: use `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following code to find application directory:

```
  let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.ApplicationDirectory,
                .UserDomainMask, true)
  NSLog("%@", dirPaths.first!);
```

To find the directory in which your binary is located can be easily identified as (already suggested by @vadian):

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!
```

Comment: Please use code NSLog("%@", NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!)

Comment: Ok, thanks. This line worked for me:
`let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(file)`

Answer (score 11):

**2020 | SWIFT 5.1:**

```
let appFolder = Bundle.main.resourceURL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `NSBundle.mainBundle()` is what you are looking for. You can use `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "txt")` to load a file

Answer (score 0):

This is what it worked for me (using iOS):

```
let directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        
if let firstURL = directoryPaths.first, let url = URL(string: firstURL)?.deletingLastPathComponent() {
    print("App files url: \(url.path)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5:

```
var appURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundleURL.absoluteString)

// Remove app from URL to get directory path
appURL.deleteLastPathComponent()
```